# Python 3: Merging list of objects with different attributes given

Tags: python, list, object, merge

I have a situation (simplified basic example below) where I have two lists consisting of custom objects with different attributes. In one list, one of the attributes is given (the other is 0 or None or empty list), and the other list contains the values for the other attribute. The two lists are not necessarily equally long, i.e. there might be some entries with no match. What I like to have is a new list (or modify one of the existing lists), which contains all unique objects with the values for the attributes taken from wherever it is given.

```
class human:
    def __init__(self, name, age=0, height=0):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height

list_1 = [human("Alice", age=25),     human("Bob", age=30),    human("Steve", age=21)]
list_2 = [human("Alice", height=170), human("Bob", height=185)]

complete_list = merge(list_1, list_2)
```

The desired output would be a list equal to:

```
complete_list = [human("Alice", age=25, height=170), human("Bob", age=30, height=185), human("Steve", age=21)]
```

Of course I could loop over both lists and check for matches, then check where my value is, then updating where it is not and so on, but that's just ugly isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code assumes names are unique, we can take advantage of that:

```
class human:
    def __init__(self, name, age=0, height=0):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height

    def merge(self, other):
        if not self.age:
            self.age = other.age
        if not self.height:
            self.height = other.height

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'human(name={}, age={}, height={})'.format(self.name, self.age, self.height)

def merge_lists(list_1, list_2):
    output = {h.name: h for h in list_1}
    for h in list_2:
        try:
            output[h.name].merge(h)
        except KeyError:
            output[h.name] = h
    return list(output.values())

list_1 = [human("Alice", age=25), human("Bob", age=30), human("Steve", age=21)]
list_2 = [human("Alice", height=170), human("Bob", height=185)]

print(merge_lists(list_1, list_2))
```

Outputs

```
[human(name=Alice, age=25, height=170),
 human(name=Bob, age=30, height=185),
 human(name=Steve, age=21, height=0)]
```

This can be taken a step further if we implement a `HumanList` class:

```
from collections import UserList
from copy import deepcopy

class human:
    def __init__(self, name, age=0, height=0):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height

    def merge(self, other):
        if not self.age:
            self.age = other.age
        if not self.height:
            self.height = other.height

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'human(name={}, age={}, height={})'.format(self.name, self.age, self.height)

class HumanList(UserList):
    def merge_lists(self, other_list):
        output = {h.name: deepcopy(h) for h in self}
        for h in other_list:
            try:
                output[h.name].merge(h)
            except KeyError:
                output[h.name] = h
        return HumanList(output.values())

list_1 = HumanList([human("Alice", age=25), human("Bob", age=30), human("Steve", age=21)])
list_2 = HumanList([human("Alice", height=170), human("Bob", height=185)])

merged_list = list_1.merge_lists(list_2)
print(merged_list)
```

Outputs

```
[human(name=Alice, age=25, height=170),
 human(name=Bob, age=30, height=185),
 human(name=Steve, age=21, height=0)]
```

Comment: Looks great, just one question: is the `output[h.name] = h` in the except clause really necessary? Seems to work fine to just pass, since the hs are already present from the creation of the dict. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @VY_CMa It is necessary in case `list_2` contains an object with name that does not appear in `list_1`, that's the only case where `output[h.name]` can raise a `KeyError`

Answer (score 0):

```
class human:
    def __init__(self, name, age=0, height=0):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height

list_1 = [human("Alice", age=25),     human("Bob", age=30),    human("Steve", age=21)]
list_2 = [human("Alice", height=170), human("Bob", height=185)]

def merge(lst1, lst2):
    d = {}

    for h in lst1:
        d[h.name] = {'age': h.age}

    for h in lst2:
        d[h.name].update({'height': h.height})
    return d

merge(list_1, list_2)
```

Returns:

```
{'Alice': {'age': 25, 'height': 170}, 'Bob': {'age': 30, 'height': 185}, 'Steve': {'age': 21}}
```

You can then create a list from the dictionary to convert to a list of humans.

```
humans_dict = merge(list_1, list_2)
humans_lst = [human(k, v.get('age', 0), v.get('height', 0)) for k, v in d.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

What's missing from your question is that you group the different entries by the person name.

I would solve it like this:

```
people = dict()
for l in [list_1,list_2]:
  for h in l:
    if h.name not in people:
      people[h.name] = h
    else:
      existingPerson = people[h.name]
      if h.age:
        existingPerson.age = h.age
      if h.height:
        existingPerson.height = h.height
```

If you had lots of attributes I'd do it like this:

```
people = dict()
for l in [list_1,list_2]:
  for h in l:
    if h.name not in people:
      people[h.name] = h
    else:
      existingPerson = people[h.name]
      for a in ['age','height']:
        v = getattr(h,a)
        if v:
          setattr(existingPerson,a,v)
```

Finally you create the complete list:

`complete_list = list(people.values())`